# React - Dynamically adding input tag using state

Tags: reactjs

I want to add new input tags to my web page when I click on Add input button.

**Attempt:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [addInput, setAddInput] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => setAddInput(true);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Add Input</button>
      {addInput ? <input type="text" /> : ""}
    </div>
  );
}
```

How can I make the above code work to dynamically add new inputs?

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, you want to add several input tags and not only one?

Comment: @khenriksson yes. that's correct. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do want you want.

```js
const [state, setState] = useState([]);

const handleClick = () => {
    let inputs = Object.assign([], state);
    inputs.push(<input type='text' key={inputs.length} />);

    setState(inputs);
}

return (
    <div className="App">
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Add Input</button>
        {state}
    </div>
);
```

You should know, added `input`s are [Uncontrolled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html).

In order to help you to learn more about the possible solutions, here is another approach:

```js
const [state, setState] = useState(0);

const handleClick = () => setState(state + 1);

const generateInputs = () => {
    const inputs = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < state; i++) inputs.push(<input key={i} type='text' />);

    return inputs;
}

return (
    <div className="App">
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Add Input</button>
        {generateInputs()}
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the additional solution and more info on Uncontrolled components. It is helpful